# MySQL Query Syntax error when updating fields using two conditions

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I'm using WordPress and i need to update a specific meta_key value for some specific post_id.

So i write this line of query

```
UPDATE `wp_postmeta`
    SET `meta_value` = '100'
    WHERE `wp_postmeta`.`post_id` IN (4100,4173) AND `meta_key` = 'data_foo’
```

But it returns this syntax error:

**#1064 - Syntax Error in SQL query near ' IN (4100,4173)AND `meta_key` = 'data_foo'' line1**

Can anyone help me?

Thank you

Comment: A space between ) and AND perhaps …?

Answer (score 1):

Try this version:

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta wp
    SET meta_value = '100'
    WHERE wp.post_id IN (4100, 4173) AND wp.meta_key = 'data_foo';
```

The only obvious syntax problem I see is that the final single quote is curly -- which is not correct for SQL.